# Почему вывод ошибку unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

> На тренировке спортсмен ежедневно пробегает некоторую дистанцию, с каждым днем увеличивая ее на 10%. Составить программу, определяющую по расстоянию, преодоленному спортсменом в первый день тренировки длину дистанции на k-ый день.

```
rast=float(input('введите расстояние, которые вы пробежали в 1-ый день тренировки'))
a=rast*0,1
for i in range(7):
    rast += a
    print('расстояние, которое вы пробежите на следующий день',rast)
```

Comment: используйте точку, а не запятую, как разделитель целой и дробной частей.

Answer (score 2):

В python, и в целом в информационных системах принято как разделитель дробной части использовать символ точки, а не запятой.

Поэтому интерпритатор ругается на то, что `rast` у вас типа float, а `а` из-за неправильного разделителя дробной части он считает кортежем (tuple).